# Why does this Regex time out?

Tags: ruby, regex

This might not be the ideal question for Stackoverflow, sorry if I really violated a guideline (like "Too localized". But this is quite an interesting problem:

I have the following Regex (a simpler version of URL matching):

```
\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z]{2,6})(\.([a-z]{2,6}))?([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)\z
```

Now if I test this string (which doesn't match, because of the special characters):

```
http://t3n.de/news/nokia-lumia-930-test-560264/?utm_source=feedburner+t3n+News+12.000er&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+aktuell%2Ffeeds%2Frss+%28t3n+News%29
```

Like this (just to make sure I didn't make an obvious error):

```
str = 'http://t3n.de/news/nokia-lumia-930-test-560264/?utm_source=feedburner+t3n+News+12.000er&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+aktuell%2Ffeeds%2Frss+%28t3n+News%29'
str.match /\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z]{2,6})(\.([a-z]{2,6}))?([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)\z/i
```

The command just runs forever. Shouldn't it return nil since the string doesn't match? I use the latest version of ruby, but this also occurs on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/2ajABaqmTE

```
jarvis:~ rudolf$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Any ideas what might cause this? Did I discover a Ruby bug or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your regex, there's this:

```
([\/\w \.-]*)*
```

which causes the regex engine to create a lot of *states* that it can possibly backtrack to. You can safely remove the last `*`:

```
([\/\w \.-]*)
```

Comment: That `.` should not get escaped and the space is unnecessary

Comment: @pguardiario, not really, the `.` *needn't* be escaped, but it makes little difference: both `[.]` and `[\.]` match the literal ".". And the literal space cannot just be removed: then the space won't be matched anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, the 2nd `*` in this part `([\/\w \.-]*)*` is redundant and causes great amounts of backtracking. Remove it and it works fine: `([\/\w \.-]*)`

You have a lot of capture groups and you might want to remove them as well if you don't intend to use them, but that won't have as big of an impact.